# Xamarin Forms Splash is not appearing in iOS 14

Tags: xamarin

I have added splash through LaunchScreen.storyboard.
1x, 2x and 3x images of splash screen used and splash image designed with iOS image view with Content Mode property to "Aspect Fill".
Now splash appearing fine up till iOS 13 devices.
**If I check in iOS 14, the splash is not showing, It is showing black screen instead.**
Does any one face the same and have any solution for it?

Comment: It seems an existing on iOS 14.0 . Here are two similar issues , you could follow up them and I will report if have any updates .https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/650913  https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/12244